# if just storing data, does using static class as global variable in c# Unity harmfull?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, global-variables

I'm currently developping turn based RPG game with Unity. For storing Player informations, monsters list and items list, I use static class.

```
public static class GlobalVariables 
{
    public static BaseMonster currentMonster;
    public static BaseCharacter player;
    public static List<BaseMonster> monsterDatabase;
    public static Dictionary<string, BaseItem> itemDatabase;
}
```

I set this values when game loading by json file than use it into all of my scenes.

I wonder if it is harmful like most people' opinions on global variables?

*Note: currentMonster is information that set when player selecting monster and Used when "fight scene" loading, to deside what Monster will load.*

Comment: Global variables aren't inherently bad. The problems start if you a) initialize them all at load time (it can slow your program start time), b) have a lot of them and fill up a lot of memory (of course instance variables can do the same, but you might not have them in memory all the time), and/or c) use them in a multi-threaded environment without safety checks.

Comment: The above comment is actually a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not acutally bad or harmfull, but I would suggest using Singelton: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern This way you only use one static member. Here is an example as well:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx